# Bootstrap Carousel displays all images at once on top of each other (HTML)

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm trying to implement a carousel on a website I'm making, however the images all load on top of each other and the carousel controls are absent. Below is my code. This code was actually copied and pasted from another website I made where it works properly. Thanks in advance for all help.

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 80px;">
    <div id="slides" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
         <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
         <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="1"></li>
         <li data-target="#slides" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
         <img class="d-block mx=auto" src="images/villager.png"  alt="Villager">
       </div>
         <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block mx=auto" src="images/vault.png"  alt="Man">
         </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block mx=auto" src="images/dragonborn.jpg"  alt="Skyrim">
         </div>
         </div>
             <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
         <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#slides" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
        </div>
```

Here is an image of how the page displays the carousel
[image: Here is an image of how the page displays the carousel]

Answer (score 2):

Problem is that

> This code was actually copied and pasted from another website I made where it works properly.

So you just copy the HTML without CSS... so copy the CSS as well.

This website porbably use [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) links. And you should modify classes `mx=auto` for `mx-auto`.